# SQL Server PK and FK always equal value

Tags: c#, sql-server, increment

I have question, how can i insert a new data into a database that the primary key and foreign key is always equal in value?

ex. i entered my name into Name table and that Name table has PK and FK. every time i insert a new data, the FK was empty. i expect that the value of FK is same as the value of PK even they have different field name.

[image]

above is my database relationship. every time i insert new data the EventsID pk(Eventstbl) wont copy to EvnetsID FK(Organizationtbl)

Comment: Can you show your table structure?

Comment: i found a tricky solution, first is use the select top 1 and desc it to get the last result and add 1. for now ill use this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The referential integrity does not work as you described. It better suits functionality of the triggers. The purpose of the PK and foreign key constraint is to prevent insertion of data which is not exist in other table as PK. Therefore, if you want to copy data from Eventstbl to Organizationtbl upon inserting a new record to the former, you need to write a trigger for the insertion event of the Eventstbl. Your PK - FK constraint will work like following, when you insert new record to Organizationtbl, it will check Eventstbl table for the corresponding EventsID. If it does not exist, it will not allow you to insert new record to Organizationtbl. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use a trigger in EventsTbl, an after insert / update trigger. So this trigger could insert / update the other table you need. You can use the INSERTED table to catch the new value of the PK. I hope it helps.